# JQuery: how to add XML node?

Tags: jquery, xml

Assume parentNode exists and I want to add an element "Child" to it. Following intutive code won't work:

```
$("<Child>").appendTo(parentNode);
```

Because jQuery will create a node  and append to parentNode.

So I am wondering, how do you add xml child node in jQuery?

p.s. Following ugly code will work, but it is really really ugly:

```
parentNode.appendChild(parentNode.ownerDocument.createElement("Child"));
```

p.s.2 `$(parentNode).append('<Child >)` won't append the child node with jQuery 1.2.6 on FireFox 3. Actually it append nothing. If use `appendTo()`, it will append a node with name CHILD (all capital).

Comment: A jQuery XML plugin would be nice, if it can create, read, write, delete nodes. Is there one out that i haven't found? I would bounty this but i have such little rep as it is :S

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is not meant to treat xml. When you use `$("<Child/>")` JQuery uses a hidden div innerHTML to build the child node, that's why the capitalization differs.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that "JQuery is not meant to treat xml." JQuery has several methods for making AJAX requests. Since the "X" in AJAX stands for XML, JQuery ought to be able to deal with this situation.

Comment: But I agree that JQuery doesn't really have very good ways of manipulating XML at the moment.